# What is the residual distribution in this regression model?

Tags: residuals, model, diagnostic

I have fitted a model

$$g(\mu) = X\beta, \ \mu = EY_i, \ Y \sim T(\nu, \mu, \sigma)$$

where $T$ is a scaled and shifted t-distribution.

This model was fitted in R (I use gam from mgcv), and pearson residuals were obtained.

The normal qqplot looks fantastic .....[image]

...... but  is this what I should be doing? Should my model residuals be normally distributed? If so, why? Is there some other type of model diagnostics I should be doing?

Comment:   is a scaled and shifted t-distribution - what do you mean by that? I didn't know mgcv has t-distributions in the extended family - could you post the model that you fit?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the distribution of your residuals **must be** normal if you are using ordinary least squares (OLS) as your loss function.  If, on the other hand, your residuals are distributed with fatter tails, you might want to use [absolute error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_absolute_deviations) since it is the maximum likelihood estimator of the Laplace Distribution.

Your linear regression predictions must come from the same distribution as the trained residuals in order to effectively minimize your loss function to a mean of zero.  If you choose a loss function that does not work for the distribution of your residuals, you cannot guarantee that predictions are effectively minimizing error.

Comment: No it does not have to be normal! Normality is needed only for confidence intervals and hypothesis tests, besides that OLS will "work" for non-normal data. You can use squared loss for whatever you want.

Comment: @Tim: The model has been fitted using penalized maxiumum likelihood regression. So, in that case, should the model residuals be approximately normal?

Comment: @Wait when using maximum likelihood you obviously make distributional assumptions since you mar maximizing the likelihood functions that is defined in terms of probability density functions of some distribution, in this case normal.